# Is separate shader objects available in OpenGL 3.1 by default?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have an issue with my code on Android.

I'm trying to use glGenProgramPipelines on my OnePlus 3, with OpenGL ES 3.1 and sady during calling this method, the app is crashing.

So my question is: Should these methods be available in OpenGL ES 3.1 or do I still need "ARB_separate_shader_objects" extension to use these?

If the extension is required, could you recommend me any Android phone which may have this extension?

Thanks!

Comment: @httpdigest, thank you! I was mislead by the OpenGL ES 3.1 on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES#OpenGL_ES_3.1 where they pointing the extensions. Also MESA drivers are exposing this extension on NVidia GeForce drivers but my Android Adreno drivers are not.